# Using recursive regex to break a list

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use recursive regex for the first time to break apart items in a list, and I'm having trouble getting multiple matches.

I have a string such as `array(string,boolean)`. I want to extract `string` and `boolean` from within, and so have this regex:

```
array\((?:([a-z]+)[,\S]*)(?:(?R)|\))
```

When testing with regex101.com, I successfully match `string`, but not `boolean`. I tried to move around some parens around in case the way I was grouping was wrong.

I'd love some advice on where I've gone wrong? Or am I misunderstanding how recursive regex works?

To help along: https://regex101.com/r/Vkmvr0/2

Comment: Do you want a php-based solution to this without regex?

Comment: Parsing code with a single regex is not safe. Using a dedicated parser is advisable.

Comment: A PHP solution is easy, which is what I'm doing now (a small regex of `array\((.+?)\)` followed by an explode, or preg_split if I want to make the split more broad). I just through it would be a nice time to learn something new as well. Thanks though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you expand on that? Why is it not safe?

Comment: Parsing `array('string (', ')((( string')` is not possible with just a `(` and `)` based recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing right, another option you would have had, might have been to use lookarounds, such as with an expression similar to:

```
(?<=\(|,)[^\r\n,)]*(?=,|\))
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LWfXew/1). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/LWfXew/1debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---